# Effiecient serialization of native java arrays with java.io

Tags: java, arrays, performance, serialization, native

I gotta question about efficient serialization with java.io. Efficient mainly in terms of computation-time. What is the fastest way to serialize and deserialize native arrays like long[], int[], short[] etc. to disk?

My arrays are of size between 100mb upto 600mb. What i can do is of course to use my outstream with out.writeInt(...) and out.readInt(...), but i guess there must be a faster (buffered?!) way, as i know i am reading in a complete array.

All i know, is that the framework gives me a DataInput which can be casted to InputStream. The rest is handled by my framework.

Thanks in advance,

Eeth

Comment: Is the external data format pre-specified or do you have control over it?

Comment: You haven't really defined the problem. Can you provide some performance numbers (I/O per second)? It could be that whatever speed you're getting is fine - but how are we to know that without some data about your issue?

Comment: normalocitY: Sorry for that. I don't have any times, but they wouldn't be much useful. (gotta SSD here, someone else has something else etc.)  I just wondered if there is a more efficient way to store complete native java arrays. aix: all i got is a input stream, i have no idea about the external dataformat... this is my problem. i just get a DataInput and want to write the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is only one method to use for each type with DataInput which is readLong etc.

If you could use memory mapped files and native byte ordering that would be much more efficient all round.

In previous tests I have done, reading `long` with a memory mapped ByteBuffer (with native byte ordering) was 6x faster than using DataInputStream.

In fact parsing text from a ByteBuffer was faster than using DataInputStream to read binary. :P

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/writing-human-readable-data-faster-than.html

Comment: So there is no way to get over this? does it make sense to first convert my whatever[] to byte[] manually and then write it with write(byte[])?

Comment: This would help if your DataOutput didn't have any buffering.  However I assumed you would be using buffering.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to stick with Java Serialization, for this particular use case Ascii Serialization also sounds good.

Decide on a simple format for data, and Use a Buffered Writer/Reader to Serialize/Deserialize. I bet that will be faster than using Java Serialization.

Plus the added advantage you get is you can see your serialized data.